# xdg-open gives error : FIPS violation detected at crypto/evp/digest.c:219, reason: SHA-1 hash algorithm is not allowed in FIPS mode

Tags: centos, chrome, cryptography, citrix

As seen from `var/log/messages` when i xdg open is triggered from the browser:

`Aug 14 11:01:43 centos org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1833986]: FIPS violation detected at crypto/evp/digest.c:219, reason: SHA-1 hash algorithm is not allowed in FIPS mode.`

[image]

How can i make sure that citrix receiver is opened when i click on Open xdg-open as shown in the image below

Comment: It sounds like you have more than one issue here.  One is that you set the security level to FIPS and so sha1 isn’t allowed by the SSL stack, the other that you are trying to use xdg-open from a browser and it is doing something, but you don’t say what.

Comment: This doesn't come from `xdg-open` itself, but from some program that `xdg-open` runs, which is determined by the file type. It's impossible to help you without knowing the file type, and which handler for this file type if it isn't something installed by default (you mention citrix receiver, which does not come with CentOS, but you don't explain how it's involved).